# Simulation of dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have following DF.

```
> x
  Members      Exp
1       A 2.575374
2       B 5.764491
3       C 7.576994
4       D 5.834233
5       E 3.977425
```

"Exp" is a Poisson distributed variable. I would now like to make simulation on whole table and see number of times on each rank for "Member".

Desired result would be something like:

Rank A B C D E
1 10%
2 18%
3 42%
4 18%
5 12%
100%

Really appreciate help here :)

Apologize but pretty new to R.

```
    sim <- 100
    a <- matrix(nrow = sim, ncol = nrow(x))

    for (i in nrow(x)){
      a[,i] <<- rpois(sim, x[i,2])
      }

colnames(a) <- x[,1]
```

I get a wrong message here,

```
Error in a[, i] <<- rpois(sim, x[i, 2]) : object 'a' not found
```

It works when I dont have it in a loop.. Idea is to count number of rows where "Member" ranks 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th and 5th.

It works now with this code

```
    sim <- 100
    a <- matrix(nrow = sim, ncol = nrow(x))

    for (i in 1:nrow(x)){
      a[,i] <- rpois(sim, x[i,2])
      }

colnames(a) <- x[,1]
```

Which gives me this dataframe

```
> head(a)
     A  B  C D E
[1,] 0  9  8 3 4
[2,] 2 10  6 3 4
[3,] 3  6  7 9 1
[4,] 2  3  4 6 1
[5,] 3  4  6 7 3
[6,] 4  3 12 5 3
```

Row 1 is simulation 1, row 2 simulation 2 and so on.. Now I want to see how many times A is Max.

What I need to do is to create a logical matrix of equal size where I apply Max on each row and than calculate average for each column. But Max will only return max value for each row, I would like to return 0 or 1 in each cell..

Comment: Your expected output is unclear and `make simulation on whole table and see number of times on each rank for "Member".` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I want to simulate "Exp" variable and than see how many times A finish 1,2,3,4 and 5. Same for members B, C, D and E.

Comment: Please edit your question to better explain it, rather than putting modifications in the comment section.

Comment: A few pointers: take a look at `?replicate`, it may help you with the simulation. Also, don't use `<<-`. Instead use `<-`. This may be the cause of your error. `<<-` should be used rarely (pretty much never).

Comment: The Poisson distribution is discrete, so the values of the 2nd column should be integers...

Comment: but lambda doesn't necessarily have to be an integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really does it, but was hoping not to use for loops :)

```
> x
  Members      Exp
1       A 2.575374
2       B 5.764491
3       C 7.576994
4       D 5.834233
5       E 3.977425

sim <- 100
a <- matrix(nrow = sim, ncol = nrow(x))
b <- matrix(nrow = sim, ncol = nrow(x))

for (i in 1:nrow(x)){
  a[,i] <- rpois(sim, x[i,2])
  }

colnames(a) <- x[,1]

for (j in 1:sim){
    for (k in 1:nrow(x)){
      b[j,k] <- as.numeric(a[j,k]) == max(a[j,])
    } 
}

head(b)

> head(b)
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
[1,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[4,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[6,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
...
sim <- 100
a <- matrix(nrow = sim, ncol = nrow(x))

for (i in nrow(x)){
  a[,i] <- rpois(sim, x[i,2])
}
```